# Has anyone publicly shared an implementation of RUSBoost in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, sampling, unbalanced-classes, boosting

There's no package available on CRAN, so I was hoping someone in the community had written their own function/package. I see it's been done in MATLAB, so I may just have to start with that and write the code myself...

[Algorithm description - "RUSBoost: Improving Classification Performance when Training Data is Skewed"](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.researchgate.net%2Fpublication%2F220928945_RUSBoost_Improving_classification_performance_when_training_data_is_skewed%2Flinks%2F0912f50f4bec36d920000000&ei=_Q3-U8mlBoqgyATK64DAAg&usg=AFQjCNE4up8eO76ym5RV7q7hPNCfvFV7Mw&sig2=mfu1xkUP_QfmhOMnOmsivQ&bvm=bv.74035653,d.aWw)

[Example of MATLAB code (which includes code for boosting in addition to the undersampling)](https://code.google.com/p/cs229-finalproject-aar-fall2012/source/browse/trunk/Code/RUSBoost/RUSBoost/RUSBoost.m?r=69)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I did it. If anyone is looking for this, you can find it at http://steveohh.github.io/RUSBoost.